# Multibib problem

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, multibib

I want to create a bibliography in two different parts: books and online. But copying the code from a working example, I don't get what I want. The second bibliography section does not come up. I assume that the problem in my newcite command, but I am not sure.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{New}{The other list}

\begin{document}

Les pommes sont rouges.\cite{aa} Il pleut en hiver!\citeNew{ca}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refa}

\bibliographystyleNew{plain}
\bibliographyNew{refc}
\end{document}
```

and my bib files:
refa

```
@Article{aa,
  author =   {Author, A.},
  title =    {Les pommes},
  journal =  {Journal},
  year =     2000
}

@Article{ab,
  author =   {Brother, B.},
  title =    {Titling},
  journal =  {Ann. J.},
  year =     2002
}
```

refc:

```
@Article{ca,
  author =   {Author, A.},
  title =    {Title},
  journal =  {Journal},
  year =     2000
}

@Article{cb,
  author =   {Brother, B.},
  title =    {Titling},
  journal =  {Ann. J.},
  year =     2002
}
```

That is what I get. (there is only one citation function that is working) I compiled pdfLaTex, BibLaTeX, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX to generate this pdf.
[image: What my compiler display]

It is also important to mention that I have all the packages updated.

Finally, what is the file type that Latex is looking for when it is written `plain`? Is it a .bst file?

Comment: It looks like you haven't run BibTeX on `New.aux`; hence, the second bibliography isn't being created.

Comment: The argument of `\bibliographystyle` has to be a file with extension `.bst`. E.g., `\bibliographystyle{plain}` tells BibTeX to look for a file called `plain.bst`.

Comment: @Mico so would it be possible to run `bibLaTeX` with referencing with an external file.bst. (I am talking about francais.bst from here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/francais-bst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code sets up two `.aux` files: `\jobname.aux`, where `\jobname` is the name of your main tex file, and `New.aux`. You need to run BibTeX on both `\jobname` and `New`. Assuming the file name of your main tex file is `main.tex`, the compilation sequence should be

```
pdflatex main
bibtex main
bibtex New
pdflatex main
pdflatex main
```

Incidentally, the bib entries don't have to be in separate bib files; they can all be in one bib file.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myrefs.bib}
@Article{aa,
  author =   {Author, A.},
  title =    {Les pommes},
  journal =  {Journal},
  year =     2000,
}
@Article{ab,
  author =   {Brontosaurus, B.},
  title =    {Bla bla},
  journal =  {Ann. J.},
  year =     2002,
}
@Article{ca,
  author =   {Chicken, C.},
  title =    {Cluck},
  journal =  {Journal},
  year =     2004,
}
@Article{cb,
  author =   {Duck, D.},
  title =    {Duck!},
  journal =  {Ann. J.},
  year =     2006,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx}

\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{New}{The other list}

\begin{document}
Les pommes sont rouges.\cite{aa} 
Il pleut en hiver.\citeNew{ca}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{myrefs}

\bibliographystyleNew{plain}
\bibliographyNew{myrefs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume that to run `BibTeX`on the main file is only by selecting this compilation function from the main file (What I did). How can I run `BibTeX` on New.aux. Is there a way to configure TexMaker or Tex Live to automatically run both files.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't tell you how to run TeXMaker as I use a different front-end editor. Do you know how to open a command window and switch to the directory that contains `main.tex`? If so, do that and type `bibtex New` at the command prompt.